# How to add Custom Tags in Worpdress

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I was trying to create custom tags for my wordpress application. I entered this piece of code to my functions.php:

```
function create_my_taxonomies() {
register_taxonomy('actors', 'post', array(
'hierarchical' => false, 'label' => 'Actors',
'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true));
register_taxonomy('producers', 'post', array(
'hierarchical' => false, 'label' => 'Producers',
'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true));
    }
add_action('init', 'create_my_taxonomies', 0);
```

When I now try to access my admin panel, it throws me this error:
**Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4209**

Then I checked and found that it's because of the **add_action()** function that it cant find. So I included **require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/plugin.php' );** at top of the **functions.php**

But now it throws me another error: **Fatal error: Cannot redeclare add_filter() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php:82)**

I tried looking up everywhere but I doesn't seem to find anything. Suggestions and help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `functions.php` should be in your theme directory, not in includes directory. Should be somewhere like `wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/functions.php`

Comment: Thanks so much Alan, u Rock!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `require`, try using `require_once` to make sure the file is included only once.

```
require_once ( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/plugin.php' );
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did that already, but the error still persists. Just one quick question, is there any chance that my wordpress files have got corrupted although if I remove the piece of code for adding custom tags, my wordpress page would work perfectly.